# Time Since Update MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have table full of timestamps similar to `2011-10-05 08:09:00.000` this is queried by the below query referencing reg_date, mid_date, pre_date. Instead of displaying the timestamp I need it to display `23 mins ago` instead of `2011-10-05 08:09:00.000`. I have tried some functions like `timediff()` and `format()`. I would like to complete this all in the query so that I do not have to query and the process the results.

Maybe I am not understanding the manaul very well but I am sure there is a way to complete this. I am really new to MySQL query statement. I see lots of potential and time saving though. I just need a little bit of help to get ths accomplished.

```
select reg_price as regPrice, _id as ID, lat, lng, reg_date as regDate, 
                mid_date as midDate, pre_date as preDate, 
                format((acos(sin(radians(39.9891)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians(39.9891)) *
                cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(-82.8116) - radians(lng))) * 6378),1)
                as distance from stationDetails where (acos(sin(radians(39.9891)) 
                * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians(39.9891)) * cos(radians(lat)) * 
                cos(radians(-82.8116) - radians(lng))) * 6378) <= 3 order by reg_price asc, reg_price asc
```

Comment: Displaying datetimes in ago format is very generic - there is no 'one' way to do it.  Do you want it always in minutes?  In minutes/hours?  minutes/hours/days/months/years?  Modeled after StackOverflow?  How do you determine when to display which format and how to display it?

Comment: I don't know what server-side language you are using but here's an easy solution in PHP: http://www.mdj.us/web-development/php-programming/another-variation-on-the-time-ago-php-function-use-mysqls-datetime-field-type/

Comment: It will be determined from the current time on the server, so it can use the `now()`. I need it to be displayed some like `3 day 2 hrs 2 mins 23 secs` Sorry for not including this in the original post.

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to your other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the function that was built for time span similar to SOF.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetTimeDisplay2` $$

CREATE FUNCTION `GetTimeDisplay2` (GivenTimestamp TIMESTAMP)

RETURNS VARCHAR(32)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN    

    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(32);

    DECLARE diff BIGINT;    

    SET diff = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GivenTimestamp);

        IF diff < 0 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(abs(diff/60),' From Now');

    END IF;

    IF diff = 0 THEN

        SET rv = 'Just Now';

    END IF;

    IF diff = 1 THEN

        SET rv = '1 sec ago';

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 2 AND 60 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff, 0), ' secs ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 120 AND 3599 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/60, 0), ' mins ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 61 AND 119 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/60, 0), ' min ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff = 3600 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/3600, 0), ' hr ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff BETWEEN 3601 AND 86399 THEN

        SET rv = CONCAT(FORMAT(diff/3600, 0), ' hrs ago');

    END IF;

    IF diff > 86400 THEN

        SET rv = DATE_FORMAT(GivenTimestamp, '%a %l:%i %p');

    END IF;

    IF diff > 259200 THEN

        SET rv = DATE_FORMAT(GivenTimestamp, '%b %e at %l:%i %p');

    END IF;

    RETURN rv;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `TIMEDIFF()` and `TIME_FORMAT()` you should be able to display results like X minutes ago.  It should be easy to modify this for other time values as needed, depending on how you want to deal with different timescales (hours, days, etc.):

```
select
    TIME_FORMAT(
        TIMEDIFF(now(), dt)
        ,'%i minute(s) ago'
    )
from Data;
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/r1mlXcM62V